# Existence of a unique solution of $dX_t=X_tB_tdB_t+X_tB_tdt, X_0=1$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Does this SDE have a unique solution:
$$dX_t=X_tB_tdB_t+X_tB_tdt, \quad X_0=1?$$

I have to check if the Lipschitz condition holds and if the growth condition holds.

I presume not, as the Brownian motion can take any value (it is unbounded, so the growth and the Lipschitz condition are not satisfied. But how can I formally prove this, if my intuition is indeed correct?

How can one generally prove/disprove the conditions for existence and uniqueness, besides showing if it is differentiable?

Comment: The classical Lipschitz conditions are for SDEs of the form $$dX_t = b(t,X_t) \,dt + \sigma(t,X_t) \, dB_t$$ where $b$ and $\sigma$ are **deterministic** functions. Note that your coefficients are not deterministic and, hence, the classical results do not apply.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. And how can I then prove whether or not a unique solution exists?

Comment: Well, there **are** general uniqueness results for SDEs with random coefficients; I'm just saying that you should be careful which kind of results are applicable.